# How to simplify this propositional logic expression (DNF)?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I simplified the original problem up to this point

`((P∧¬R)∨(¬Q∨R))∧((Q∧¬R)∨(¬P∨R))`

, and I got stuck here. What would be the next step? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: let me use pen and paper. You should read the basics by the way.

Comment: it can be solved from where you simplified. Try once. It is fun.

Comment: What is the asterisk in the original?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, added asterisk to show what my edit was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am solving it with you.

Hint-1:   `((P∧Q)∨R) = (PVR) ∧ (QVR)`

Hint-2:    `P ∧ True = P`

Hint-3:    `P V True = True`

### Answer

It would be true in the end. Check it once.

Next step would be

```
= [(P V (~Q V R)) ^ ( ~R V (~Q V R))]
 ^[(Q V (~P V R)) ^ ( ~R V (~P V R))]

= (P V ~Q V R) ^ ( ~p V Q V R)
= R V (  (P V ~Q) ^ ( Q V ~P))
= R v ((  Q -> P ) ^ ( P -> Q))   
= R V (P <-> Q)
```

whenever R is True  it is True.
Else

```
  P  Q   P<->Q
------------------
   F F      T
   F T      F
   T F      F
   T T      T
```

So  it conforms to the truth table. Shown above by **trincot**.

Comment: @trincot.: thanks...yea. I wrote it wrong but using the correct formual. Thanks

Comment: Did you simplify it from there? It contardicts somehow..maybe Iyou simplified the first statement wrong.

Comment: @BenJoe.: Hope it helps

Comment: @coderredoc ty, in my class we have not distributed in that way yet. much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions are equivalent:

(p ⇒ r) ⇔ (q ⇒ r)

(¬p v r) ⇔ (¬q v r)

(¬p ⇔ ¬q) v r

(p ⇔ q) v r

(p ∧ q) v (¬p ∧ ¬q) v r

**Truth table:**

```
p  q  r  result
---------------
0  0  0    1
0  0  1    1
0  1  0    0
0  1  1    1
1  0  0    0
1  0  1    1
1  1  0    1
1  1  1    1
```

Comment: alot simpler than what I was doing!